# How do I make both Images stay when they are matched and flip back when they don't match (Memory Matching Game)?

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing an Android Game app (Memory Game), in which the objective of the game is to match 2 identical images until all the images in the grid are matched. Only 2 Images are revealed at a time, and if both images match, they will stay, and if they don't, they will flip back. I am still a beginner in Java.

```
package jimosman311.gmail.com.j39712_co5025_asg;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

int count;
Button[] Buttons = new Button[9];
int[] myImageArr = new int[]{R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.grape, R.drawable.grape, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.watermelon, R.drawable.watermelon};
int[] click1, click2;
Handler handler;
Runnable r;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    handler = new Handler();
    r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            flipbacktimer();
        }
    };


    //Randomize Images
    randomize(myImageArr, myImageArr.length);

    //Reference FindViewID

    Buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    Buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    Buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    Buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    Buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    Buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
    Buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    Buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    Buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

    Button newgameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgamebutton2);

    //Set OnClick Listener

    Buttons[0].setOnClickListener(this);
    Buttons[1].setOnClickListener(this);
    Buttons[2].setOnClickListener(this);
    Buttons[3].setOnClickListener(this);
    Buttons[4].setOnClickListener(this);
    Buttons[5].setOnClickListener(this);
    Buttons[6].setOnClickListener(this);
    Buttons[7].setOnClickListener(this);
    Buttons[8].setOnClickListener(this);

    newgameButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Clear Grid of Numbers

    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        Buttons[i].setText("");
        Buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
    }
}

public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    stopHandler();//stop first and then start
    startHandler();
}

public void stopHandler() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
}


public void startHandler() {
    handler.postDelayed(r, 3000);
}


public void cleargrid() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        if (Buttons[i].getResources() != null) {
            Buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(0);
            Buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
        }
        randomize(myImageArr, myImageArr.length);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    startHandler();

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.one:
            count++;
            Buttons[0].setEnabled(false);
            if (count > 2) flipback();
            Buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(myImageArr[0]);
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound2).start();
            break;

        case R.id.two:
            count++;
            Buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
            if (count > 2) flipback();
            Buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(myImageArr[1]);
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound2).start();
            break;

        case R.id.three:
            count++;
            Buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            if (count > 2) flipback();
            Buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(myImageArr[2]);
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound2).start();
            break;

        case R.id.four:
            count++;
            Buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
            if (count > 2) flipback();
            Buttons[3].setBackgroundResource(myImageArr[3]);
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound2).start();
            break;

        case R.id.five:
            count++;
            Buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
            if (count > 2) flipback();
            Buttons[4].setBackgroundResource(myImageArr[4]);
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound2).start();
            break;

        case R.id.six:
            count++;
            Buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
            if (count > 2) flipback();
            Buttons[5].setBackgroundResource(myImageArr[5]);
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound2).start();
            break;

        case R.id.seven:
            count++;
            Buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
            if (count > 2) flipback();
            Buttons[6].setBackgroundResource(myImageArr[6]);
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound2).start();
            break;

        case R.id.eight:
            count++;
            Buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
            if (count > 2) flipback();
            Buttons[7].setBackgroundResource(myImageArr[7]);
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound2).start();
            break;

        case R.id.nine:
            break;

        case R.id.newgamebutton2:
            cleargrid();
            MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound).start();
            break;

    }

}

static void randomize(int arr[], int n) {
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = n - 2; i > 1; i--) {
        int j = r.nextInt(i);

        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

public void flipbacktimer() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= myImageArr.length; i++) {
        if (Buttons[i].getResources() != null) {
            Buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(0);
            Buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}

public void flipback() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= myImageArr.length; i++){
        if(Buttons[i].getResources() != null) {
            Buttons[i].setBackgroundResource(0);
            Buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: pseudocode: `if(image1.type.equals(image2.type) {matchedImages.add(image1); matchedImages.add(image2); })` now you need to ignore the clicks on the images that are in `matchedImages` list, as they are already matched.

Comment: You should state a clear question, for example describe where exactly in the code you are stuck and what puzzles you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just leave images as they are, even if they names are different, and just create class to hold them:

```
            public class GameImages {

                int image;
                boolean isMatched;

                public GameImages(int image) {

                    this.image = image;
                    this.isMatched = false;

        }

                public GameImages(int image, int id, isMatched) {

                    this.image = image;
                    this.isMatched = isMatched;

        }
```

And now create Array of GameImage's. You will use id to match images with buttons, and check if isMatched(), to leave it, and set button clickable attribute 'false', or flip it back.

Answer (score 0):

Make an object with the image and id ex {"image": your image , "id": id of the image }
put two images with same id's and when they match you are good to go